# How to create a html table with database fields and respective files uploaded to server

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a table that displays file descriptions(From mySQL database) and their respective files in my server.
The file details are uploaded on a HTML form together with the respective file. 
Here is the code, (It displays a deformed incorrect table)

```
<?php
     #Displaying files
    $getgus = "SELECT name,description,price,platform,compatible_devices,type,date,downloads,filename FROM software ORDER BY downloads desc";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$getgus)
    or die("SELECT Error: ".mysqli_error()); 

    print "<table border=1>\n"; 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //To create field titles
    $arr = array_merge([ 0 => ['Name','Description','Price','Platform','Compatible','Type','Date Uploaded','Downloads','filename']],$row);
    foreach ($arr as $v){ 
    $files_field= $arr['filename'];
    $files_show= "uploads/$files_field";
    $namevalue= $arr['name'];
    $descriptionvalue = $arr['description'];
    $pricevalue = $arr['price'];
    $platformvalue = $arr['platform'];
    $compatiblevalue = $arr['compatible_devices'];
    $genrevalue = $arr['type'];
    $datevalue = $arr['date'];
    $downloadsvalue = $arr['downloads'];
    $filenamevalue = $arr['filename'];

    print "<tr>\n"; 
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$namevalue</font>";
    print "<tr>\n"; 
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$descriptionvalue</font>";
    print "<tr>\n"; 
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$pricevalue</font>";
    print "<tr>\n"; 
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$platformvalue</font>";
    print "<tr>\n"; 
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$compatiblevalue</font>";
    print "</td>\n";
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$genrevalue</font>";
    print "</td>\n";
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$compatiblevalue</font>";
    print "</td>\n";
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$datevalue</font>";
    print "</td>\n";
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$downloadsvalue</font>";
    print "</td>\n";
    print "\t<td>\n"; 
    echo "<div align=center><a href='$files_show'>Download</a></div>";
    print "</td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n"; 
    } 
    print "</table>\n"; 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
print "\t<td>\n"; 
echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$descriptionvalue</font>";
print "<tr>\n";
```

You open the `td` tag here, then open a new `tr` tag.
You have to close the `td` with `</td>` as well as the `tr` with `</tr>` before you can open a new row.